# Insert Record into Table Wrong Syntax for MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, forms, express

I am trying to insert a record into my MySQL table. When I submit my form, it puts a post request to '/admin', which inserts the posted data into the events table.

However, instead of inserting the record, the query keeps on giving me an error, because of `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR`. To fix this, I looked at many sample insert queries for mysql, but I still do not know what I am doing wrong. Can someone give me a hand with this? Thank you!

Image of Error:

[image: image of error]

Image of mySQL table structure:
[image: image of mysql table]

```
app.post('/admin', upload.none(), function(req, res) {
        //store the event
    var event_date = convertDateFormat(req.body.date);
    var start_time = convertTimeStringTo24Hours(req.body.starttime);
    var end_time = convertTimeStringTo24Hours(req.body.endtime);
    var sql = 
        "INSERT INTO events"
        + " (name, description, start_time, end_time, location, max_capacity, hidden_sign_up, other)"
        + " VALUES ?";
    var values = [
        req.body.eventname, 
        req.body.description, 
        event_date + " " + start_time,
        event_date + " " + end_time, 
        req.body.location, 
        req.body.attendee, 
        0, 
        ""
    ];
    con.query(sql, values, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err
        res.redirect('/admin')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need as many parameters as there are values to insert in the table, enclosed with parenthesis.

So you would need to replace this:

```
var sql = 
    "INSERT INTO events"
    + " (name, description, start_time, end_time, location, max_capacity, hidden_sign_up, other)"
    + " VALUES ?";
```

With:

```
var sql = 
    "INSERT INTO events"
    + " (name, description, start_time, end_time, location, max_capacity, hidden_sign_up, other)"
    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

As far as concerned you don't need to change the rest of your code (bind parameters should be passed as an array, which you are already doing).